# Unable to connect to google cloud instance mongo with mongocompass

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I hosted a mongodb in the google cloud instance. I want to use mongocompass on my local to connect to the mongo instance in the google cloud.

my mongd.conf network interfaces is as such

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

However, when i type in my google cloud static ip and port 27017 in mongocompass, i cannot connect. How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you created a firewall rule that allows access to the port 27017 of the MongoDB instance from outside?

Comment: i disabled firewall by systemctl stop firewall. still unable to connect

Comment: I meant a VPC firewall rule: `GCP Console => VPC network => Firewall rules => Create Firewall Rule`. This rule should allow Ingress traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 (if you accept connections from all networks) to the specified TCP port 27017 of all instances in your VPC network or a particular instances marked with Network tag.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adding my white-listing my IP address under Clusters -> security -> IP Whitelist. Instead of clicking `my current ip address`, just search what's my ip on google and paste that instead. I hope it works!

Comment: Hi, is this in my local or remote cloud instance mongo?

Comment: Remote cloud instance

Comment: Sorry, is there a way i can do this via the terminal? I dont have the mongodb atlas gui